# C++ Builder 2007 TSQLDataSet - Pushing record data to a ListBox?

Tags: c++builder, dbexpress

For some background: I've been tasked with migrating a monster of a C++ application from it's current database platform to something SQL driven.  C++ is a language I've only recently started re-familiarizing myself with and I've built my share of desktop applications but never connected one to a SQL database before.  And I'm stuck with RAD Studio/C++ Builder 2007 for the moment, and I'm using dbexpress components since I don't really know better at this point.  So please excuse my possibly blunt/novice questions here.

I've taken the development environment offline and installed MySQL on a laptop.  Keeping it real basic and just building a super simple application to start with since I have a lot of learning to do still.  Frankly I'm impressed that I figured out how to get the MySQL database connected and usable in C++ Builder at all. XD

I suppose I can't realistically ask anyone here to write this simple process for me... but my goal here is to just pull in all records in a table, and just add the first field (for each record) in the table to a listbox.  For the sake of this example, lets say the table is called 'testtable' and the first field is called 'testfield1'.  There are 2 records in the table.  Surprisingly difficult to find examples of this out there... unless it's just way more complicated than I'm picturing it.

I'd appreciate any advice or suggestions folks may have.  It's probably not as simple as plopping some function of SQLDataSet1 into the ??? below... but that's where my struggle lies.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int i;

    SQLDataSet1->CommandType = ctQuery;
    SQLDataSet1->CommandText = "SELECT * FROM testtable";

    SQLDataSet1->Open();

    if (SQLDataSet1->Active)
    {
        ListBox1->Items->Clear();
        for (i = 0; i > SQLDataSet1->RecordCount; i++)
        {
            ListBox1->Items->Add(???);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all of the dataset components are derived from TDataSet. When the dataset is active, just one record is pointed to at any one time. Methods such as First and Next can be used to move a cursor to a different record. The record is held in the Fields property.

```
if (SQLDataSet1->Active)
{
    ListBox1->Items->Clear();
    SQLDataSet1->First();
    ListBox1->Items->Add(SQLDataSet1->Field[0]->AsString);

    // ...
}
```